# Is there a way to get transform with template to html?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-templates

I am using bootbox, I need display product information in it. The product information is returned as json with rest call. I am thinking using a template, and transform from the json to html. I need ng-repeat etc, in the template. The idea way is I can call template and get a html result.

But it seems angularjs $compile need bind to element to render. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ng-include:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('productCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.productInfos = [];
});
```

Use  ng-include (You have to the adjust the path depending the location of your template)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="productCtrl"> 
  <div ng-include="'product-information.html'"></div>
</div>
```

You can do *ng-repeat* in *product-information.html*:

```html
<div ng-repeat= "info in  productInfos"> {{ info.prop1 }}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That is not ideal, but I guess it is still acceptable, I kindly tried that, but how do I get the final html? since I need display them in a dialog, I am using bootbox. So I need do bootbox.alert(html)